# Proving the continuity of probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

${A_n}$ is a sequence of increasing events. Then I want to prove that $P(\cup A_n)$ is the least upper bound of the sequence $P(A_n)$. I am able to prove that it is an upper bound, but stuck in proving that it is indeed "least" upper bound.

BTW, I don't want the usual proof of "continuity of probability" from the probability axioms where we break the union into disjoint sets.

Comment: I think it might help to write $B_{n} = A_{n} - \bigcup_{i<n} A_{i}$, so that $\bigcup A_n = \bigcup B_n$ and the $B_n$'s are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: So, in the proof you want, what are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to take the $A_n$ and "disjointize" them as follows.

Let $B_1=A_1$, $B_2=A_2\setminus A_1$, $B_3=A_3\setminus A_2$, and generally $B_n=A_n\setminus A_{n-1}$. Since $A_1\subset A_2\subset \cdots$ then the $B_n$ are disjoint and so we get that $\cup_{n=1}^j B_n=\cup_{n=1}^j A_n=A_j$, for $1\leq j\leq\infty$ where $A_\infty=\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ by definition. Since the $B_n$ are disjoint then we have that $P(A_\infty)=P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(B_n)$. Let $b_j=\sum_{n=1}^j B_n$. Then notice that $P(A_j)=b_j$ for $1\leq j\leq\infty$ and $b_j\rightarrow b_\infty$. Thus it just reduces to show that if you have a sequence of montone increasing reals ($b_j$) that converge to a point $(b_\infty)$ then the limit is the sup of the sequence.

Comment: I think you want $B_n = A_n - B_{n-1}$ or something to ensure pairwise disjoint-ness.

Comment: I think what I said is right because the $A_n$ are increasing.

Comment: Plz see my modification of problem statement.

Comment: If whoever downvoted can explain (BTW I wrote the solution before the OP edited to say to not use the argument I use). Also, I don't think you can get around it. In some sense this argument is the reason it is true, so I doubt there is a proof that doesn't use this argument in some way.

Comment: I think you mean supremum, not infimum.

Comment: @dfeuer: Yes of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of events $\{A_{n}\}$ then, it is true that $A_{n} \subseteq \cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k}$. So, using measure property we have:
$$P(A_{n}) \leq P(\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_{k})$$
There you have that is the least upper bound for the sequence $P(A_{n})$.

Comment: I am not so convinced by this. Won't you elaborate?

Comment: The result shows you that you have an upper bound for $P(A_{n})$. You don't need to have a increasing sequence of events $A_{n}$, it doesn't matter. So if you are taking the union starting from $k=n$ then $\cup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_{k} \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}$. that's why I say that it is the least upper bound.