# non-atomic measure standard proof

Tags: measure-theory

I'm pretty new into fundamentals of probability and measure theory. I have no background on real analysis at all, so, I'm having trouble understanding a simple proof I found in this link:

https://paulrs.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/non-atomic-measures/

Specifically, could somebody please explain me the proof of Lemma 1? How is that the guy says, we are done, but he doesn't mention how he proved the existance of such subset \F_{\epsilon}.

Moreover, I have looked at the notes of professor Dembo, which can be found here:
[https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/TEACHING/Stat310A/lnotes.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emontanar/TEACHING/Stat310A/lnotes.pdf)

And, I found a Hint for Exercise 1.1.8, which seems to be related to this problem but and to the information provided in the first link.

However, I have no clue.

Please help.

Thanks.

Just to clarify, I would like to copy the Lemma, and its demonstration here:

> Lemma 1 Given ${G\in \mathcal{M}}$ with ${0< \mu(G) < \infty}$ and ${\varepsilon > 0}$, there is ${F_{\varepsilon}\subseteq G}$ such that ${ 0 < \mu\left( F_{\varepsilon} \right) < \varepsilon}$.
>
> Proof: Since ${\mu}$ is non-atomic, there is ${R\subseteq G}$ such that ${0<\mu(R)<\mu(G)}$, but then also ${\mu(R)+\mu\left(G\setminus R\right) = \mu(G)}$. Hence one of ${\{R,G\setminus R\}}$ must satsify ${0 < \mu\left(R_1\right) \leq \tfrac{1}{2}\cdot \mu(G)}$ (note that both have positive measure), let ${R_1}$ be that element. Continuing in this manner with ${R_1}$ we get ${R_2\subseteq R_1}$ such that ${\mu\left(R_2\right)\leq \tfrac{1}{2}\cdot \mu\left(R_1\right) \leq \tfrac{1}{2^2}\mu\left(G\right)}$, and so on. Since ${\tfrac{1}{2^n}\cdot\mu\left(G\right)\rightarrow 0}$ we are done. $\Box$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want a set $F\subset E$ such that $0<\mu(F)\leq\epsilon$. The author has demonstrated that for all $n$, there exists a set $R_n\subset E$ with $0<\mu(R_n)\leq\frac1{2^n}\mu(E)$. Now take $n$ big enough so that $\frac1{2^n}\leq\epsilon$. Then $R_n$ is your set $F$. For example, you could take $F:=R_{\lceil\log_{\frac12}\epsilon\rceil}$, where $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ indicates the ceiling function.

An alternative method would be as follows. We know that, since the space is non-atomic, there exists some $F\subset E$ with $0<\mu(F)<\mu(E)$. If one such $F$ has $\mu(F)\leq\epsilon$ then we're done. But suppose every single one has $\mu(F)\geq\epsilon$. Surely then if we take "the smallest" $F$, it would be an atomic set, since nothing could be smaller than it.

Groping around for a way to formalize this idea, we define $\mathcal F = \{F\mid F\subset E, \mu(F)>0\}$ and $m=\inf\{\mu(F)\mid F\in\mathcal F\}$, the "smallest" measure of any subet in $E$. We're saying that if $m>\epsilon$, this should lead to a contradiction. The "smallest $F$" would be the intersection of all the $F$ in $\mathcal F$, but this is an intersection of a potentially uncountable number of sets, and thus not necessarily measurable. But that's fine, we only need countably many. Take a sequence $F_n\in\mathcal F$ with $\mu(F_n)\to m$ (guaranteed to exist since $m$ is defind as an infinimum), and define $F=\bigcap F_n$.

We can prove $\mu(F)=m$, but I don't want to get into it here (it's a standard theorem in probability theory called "contuity of probability" or something like that, you can see a proof of a related theorem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463659/proving-the-continuity-of-probability)). Since $F$ is in $E$, any subset of $F$ either has $\mu(F)=m$ or $\mu(F)=0$, so $F$ is atomic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I understand better, so It means that for any arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, we can always find a subset $R \subset G$ that has some measure that is different from zero, at least, the measure is $\epsilon$. Am I correct? Sorry, I just need to formalize my understanding. Okay, then, given your explanation @Jack-M, in your notation $E$ corresponds to $G$?...

And how is this related to the hint in Professor Dembo's book? My intuition is telling me that the proof on the blog is basically what the hint is suggesting to do.

I appreciate your help.  

Thanks so much.

Comment: The idea is to prove that $E$ contains sets of arbitrarily small *but non-zero* measure - the measure of $R$ is *less* than $\epsilon$, not at least $\epsilon$. The hint from that book is for part (b) of the question, so it's not directly related to the lemma.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying reply. 
I see you still talk about $E$ but not about $G$. So, my guess is that your are considering the original Exercise 1 problem. In the particular case of Lemma 1, Can I say: Given a measure space $(X,M,\mu)$, there is a set $G$ with fixed measure $\mu(G)>0$. Then for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a subset $F\subset G$ that satisfies $0<\mu(F)<\epsilon$. Then, By the proof of Lemma 1, we can infer that subset $F$ is formed by the $R$'s ? like unions of them.. ?

Comment: @htennek2k No unions necessary. The set $F$ is one of the $R$-s. I'll edit my answer slightly to be more explicit.

Comment: We basically want to show that there are arbitrarily small subsets in $E$. The proof just consists in chopping $E$ in half until you get a small enough piece.

Comment: Ok. A lot clearer now. Thanks for your help.  I think this is a nice result. Since I'm new in this field, I'm just wondering how the author came up with this idea? Or is it a standard approach? Would you had approached the problem in the same way? Thanks.

Comment: The proof strikes me as very natural. I edited in an alternative proof, based on the basic idea that popped into my head before I read the proof you linked, after I read the theorem statement. As you can see, it's quite a bit more convoluted, but it works.

Comment: Perfect!. Appreciate your support and patience to explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: In order to invoke the continuity of the measure, you'd need the $(F_n)_n$ to be a descendent chain of sets (wrt the set inclusion relation), which in your case is not guaranteed